# Can I use ng-click to bind data to another element with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

New to Angular and experimenting with it to replace some jQuery functionality.

I have a basic UL/LI setup with countries and provinces:

```
<div ng-app="FindRep">
  <ul class="country-list" ng-controller="LocController">
    <li data-ng-repeat="country in countries">
      <a data-repId="{{country.repId || '-1'}}">{{country.Name}}</a>
      <ul class="provinces-list" style="display: none">
        <li data-ng-repeat="province in country.provinces">
          <a data-repId="{{province.repId}}">{{province.Name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Testing here -->
  RepID: {{RepID}}
</div>
```

The way I built this with jQuery, before experimenting with Angular, is if a country had a rep that existed for that entire country, as in didn't equal "-1", I would move to the next step, grab the RepID from a HTML5 data attribute:

```
var repId = $(this).data("repid");
```

And then proceed with other operations irrelevant to the question based on that ID.

If a rep did NOT exist for that country, that means there are individual reps for the provinces of that country, and I would use jQuery to show the list of provinces, allowing the user to click on one of them, and then proceed with other operations based on that repID.

This is probably very simple, but I keep reaching to jQuery, which I think is a common problem.

I'm pulling my initial data in via Web API. What I'd like to understand/figure out how to do is:

1. Create the show/hide of the UL with class provinces-list if repId = "-1".
2. Basically it proceeds until either a country or province has a rep, and once it does:
3. Have the ability to bind any data attribute I want anywhere else within the scope of the app.

So if I have:

```
<div ng-app="FindRep">
   Anywhere within my app, I'd like to be able to use {{repId}} {{repName}} and so on.
</div>
```

**What I've Tried**

I tried to use a factory to hold initial blank data about a rep, such as:

```
app.factory("rep", function() {
  var data = {
    repid: null,
    repname: ''
  };

  return {
    GetRepId: function() {
      return data.RepID
    },
    etc.
  }
```

And then using ng-click to call this function and access data from (this).

I'm rambling on, and I think I just need an example, or a push in the right direction. It's harder than I thought grasping this concept without using jQuery as a crutch.

Comment: I think you might be making this more difficult than it really is;  do you want to use a chat room to discuss your code in more detail?

Comment: Sure, never used the chat... how is it initiated?

Comment: I created a room for use for this question; http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76207/angular-js-ng-click-usage

Comment: @Claies Watching for you to post an answer with a mention of the chat, and summary so I can upvote and accept. Thank you for all your help.